# changing the sequence of the value shown in the Multimap

Tags: java, guava

I am working on Multimap, i have a simple scenario where i'm adding the key value pair to the Multimap.
Below is the sample code:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
public class MatchingTest {
    void loanApplication(final boolean loanApproved) {
        final String text1 = "Loan";
        final String text2 = "Home";
        final Multimap<String, String> matchingMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

        if (loanApproved) {
            matchingMap.put(text1 + ":" + text2, "getLoan");
        }
        matchingMap.put(text1 + ":" + text2, "setLoan");
        if (!loanApproved) {
            matchingMap.put(text1 + ":" + text2, "applyLoan");
        }
        System.out.println("matchingMap :: " + matchingMap);
    }
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new MatchingTest().loanApplication(true);
        new MatchingTest().loanApplication(false);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
matchingMap :: {Loan:Home=[getLoan, setLoan, applyLoan]}
matchingMap :: {Loan:Home=[setLoan, applyLoan]}
```

expected output:

```
matchingMap :: {Loan:Home=[getLoan, setLoan]}
matchingMap :: {Loan:Home=[applyLoan, setLoan]}
```

Is there a way that the value in the matchingMap always the setLoan value should be in the the last one to show in the value shown without changing the
steps given in the class above,i know that the values are shown in the sequence we have put in the class, but i cannot change the steps written in the class.
So is there any logic(sorting logic to show the values) where we can control what values should be shown first in the matchingMap value pair.

Other Scenario is i want to delete one value from the values shown in the Multimap value pair.

EX)In the below output, when there are getLoan and setLoan values then i should not add applyLoan to the values pair.

Expected output:

```
matchingMap :: {Loan:Home=[getLoan, setLoan]} // applyLoan is removed
matchingMap :: {Loan:Home=[setLoan, applyLoan]}
```

Comment: If you cannot change the steps of this class, where can you change or introduce any new logic?

Answer (score 0):

So the best approach would be to use `if-else` instead of multiple `if` statements as follows.

```
    if (loanApproved) {
        matchingMap.put(text1 + ":" + text2, "getLoan");
    } else {
        matchingMap.put(text1 + ":" + text2, "applyLoan");
    }
    matchingMap.put(text1 + ":" + text2, "setLoan");
```

But if you cannot change the steps of this class, where can you change or introduce any new logic?

Comment: I cannot change the steps but can add logic something as said by @AxelH which may keep the order as expected.

Answer (score 0):

A solution, if you don't want to touch the logic itself would be to change the initialisation.

Using a [`TreeMultiMap`](https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html) and `Comparator` on values to always put the `set##` after everything else.

A quick code :

```
final TreeMultimap<String, String> matchingMap = TreeMultimap.create(
            Comparator.naturalOrder(),
            (s1, s2) -> s1.startsWith("set") ? 1 : -1
            );
```

This would give :

```
matchingMap :: {Loan:Home=[getLoan, setLoan]}
matchingMap :: {Loan:Home=[applyLoan, setLoan]}
```

Comment: @AlexH - When using the TreeMultimap, it is showing errors near Comparator and s1,s2. Can you please brief what are s1 and s2. My sample code is in the above post.. It is showing the error  References to interface static methods are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above..I should not change the source level.thanks

Comment: Are you in Java 8 or above ? This is a lambda expression, shorter than writing an anonymous class like `new Compartor(){ public int compare(String s1, String s2) ...` but exactly the same idea. I used your code, just replace your declaration by mine to make it work

Comment: Please don't use contract-violating comparators.  You might use Comparator.comparing(s -> s.startsWith("set")) instead.